# Why would the bartender do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, calvary

There are hints in 2014 Irish movie Calvary that the barman murdered Father James's dog, as explained in [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18863/2089).

Why would the barman do this? I did not notice prior to this event indications that he held any grudges.

Comment: Is it actually *clear* that the bartender was it? If not, this might be better served as a comment asking for clarification on the answer you got that from, rather than a question whose premise isn't entirely clear to begin with. All in all, this seems to be pretty much a duplicate of the linked question and any deficiencies in the answers to that one ought to better be adressed *there*. Explanations for *why* the dog was killed seem to be necessary when answering by *whom*.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however it is a completely different question. Further the other one has already been answered and thus virtually "closed", nobody will reply to a question-in-comment there.